# Django field value not showing in the template

Tags: django

I have the following query but when I loop over in my template it doesn't show the name field value.

## views.py

```
hashtags = PhotoHashtag.objects.values('hashtag__name')\
    .filter(hashtag__hashtagtype_id=3)\
    .annotate(total_photos=Count('photo_id'))\
    .order_by('-total_photos')
```

## models.py

```
class PhotoHashtag(TimeStampedModel):
    photo = models.ForeignKey('posts.Photo')
    hashtag = models.ForeignKey('hashtags.Hashtag')

class Hashtag(TimeStampedModel):
    hashtagtype = models.ForeignKey('hashtags.HashtagType')

    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
```

## template

```
{% for hashtag in hashtags %}
   <li>({{ hashtag.name }}) ({{ hashtag.total_photos }})</li>
{% endfor %}
```

## sql result

[image]

## html

- () (5)
- () (2)

As you can see it shows the total_photos value but not the name value

Comment: Can you show the resulting queryset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a queryset of Hashtag objects. You have a ValuesQuerySet, created from the PhotoHashtag model, with two fields, `hashtag__name` and `total_photos`.

Comment: Can you tell me what I need to change to get the field value of name. Thanks

Comment: @Yannick you have the value you want, but with `hashtag__name` name, because you are using `.values()` function.

Answer (score 1):

`QuerySet.values` returns a dictionary-like object `ValuesQuerySet`. This is why you can filter it.

The reason `{{ hashtag.total_photos }}` works is because `'total_photos'` is a key in the resulting `ValuesQuerySet` object. Other keys in there are `'hashtag__name'` and `'total_photos'`. You can access them directly either by dot notation or like in a dict object if you're using something like Jinja2.

To make this work, just replace what you have with this:

```
{% for hashtag in hashtags %}
    <li>({{ hashtag.hashtag__name }}) ({{ hashtag.total_photos }})</li>
{% endfor %}
```